# Concatenar variable estática de clase en un string PHP

Tags: php, string

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
     protected static string $tableName = 'xxx';


     public static function printSomething(string $token): void
     {
         // ...
     }
}

Foo::printSql('asahysiahys');
```

Al llamar al método `printSomething()` espero que me imprima un string con el contenido de la propiedad estática `$tableName` y con el valor que se pasa como parámetro, dentro del método puedo usar:

```
$tableName = self::$tableName;
echo "Tabla {$tableName} @token: '{$token}'";
```

o bien:

```
echo "Tabla " . self::$tableName . " @token: '{$token}'";
```

Quiero saber si puedo usar la primera forma de concatenar strings, es decir entre comillas dobles, "marcando" como variable la propiedad estática poniendola entre llaves, algo como:

```
echo "Tabla {self::$tableName} @token = '{$token}'"; 
// {self::$tableName} NO funciona
```

Comment: po rque usas esto para concatenar `{` `}` estoy casi seguro que esta demas.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php) sin más: `printf("Tabla %s @token = %s",self::$tableName,$token);`

Answer (score 1):

No. No es posible debido a que el [analizador de variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) de PHP no lo interpreta como tal.

Por empezar, en la línea:

```php
echo "Tabla {self::$tableName} @token = '{$token}'";
```

No funciona `self::$tableName` como es esperado porque el analizador solo "*hace su trabajo*" si después de la llave hay un signo **$**, caso contrario lo imprime literal. Para que funcione tendrías que usar otra llave justo después del signo. Pero...

Cuando se usa una [sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) (entre llaves) todas las variables estáticas son interpretadas como un **nombre de variable** estática en el **ámbito en el que está definido la cadena**.

Ejemplo:

```php
class clase
{
    static public $saludo = 'hola';

    public static function mensaje(string $cadena)
    {
        $hola = 'adios';
        return "{${self::$saludo}} {$cadena}";
    }
}

echo clase::mensaje('mundo');
// Imprime: adios mundo
```

Comment: para que tantas llaves... que no basta con: `return self::$saludo.' '.$cadena;`

Comment: Lo peor es que usar llaves, puede provocar algun error a la larga de tipeo de parte del desarrollador y podrias terminar imprimiendo el nombre de la variable poco recomendado.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Sí, es lo más efectivo ya que con el primer método que preguntó no es posible hacerlo por el ámbito y la forma de trabajar del Analizador de Variables.